# Is there a way to force a variant in Google Optimize?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-optimize, gtag.js

Here Google explains [how to get the Google Optimize variant and change your page accordingly using `gtag`](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383?hl=en).

What I need to do is to be able to **set** the variant number for a specific experiment with Javascript (as early as possible in the page). And **then** the the page variant is shown and analytics data measures the variant I've set previously.